# Does marking a question as "favorite" imply that the question is high quality?

Tags: discussion, bookmarks

Sometimes I will see a question that I wouldn't upvote but would like to mark as a "favorite" (e.g. to follow it, or to remind myself to think about it later).

> Does marking a question as "favorite" imply that it's a high quality question?  Alternatively, does it send the message "this is a good question!" to the OP the same way that an upvote does?

If so, I might stick to bookmarking such questions in my browser instead of marking them as "favorite" in the future...

Comment: "Necessarily" is sort of a weird word to use in this situation.

Comment: Noted; it's been removed.

Comment: Of course, one can point out that the questioner himself could mark his question as "favorite"; on the other hand, one cannot upvote his own question.

Comment: I wish SE has a separate page where we can take notes and bookmark pages (either privately or publicly).

Answer (score 18):

As I see it, the favorite star implies "worth revisiting, for whatever reason".

There are a few badges the OP will earn at 10, 25, and 100 favorites -- if you can ask a question that a lot of people think is worth revisiting, I believe that is noteworthy.

Answer (score 13):

It doesn't. As you yourself noted, people sometimes mark a question as favourite so they can revisit it later, to add an answer etc.

Of course, that does not mean a question asker will not take it that way (especially someone new to the site). They might well think that they have asked a stellar question...

Comment: ... and use the "favorite" as evidence when they complain that their question was unfairly closed ...