# Why can someone make his/her own question as favorite?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I think it makes no sense to allow a user to make his/her own question as favorite.

Comment: Related information [Does marking a question as favorite imply that the question is of hight quality?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2337/does-marking-a-question-as-favorite-imply-that-the-question-is-high-quality?rq=1).  You'll learn people favorite posts for many different purposes, to have easy access back to the question, to be able to access the link to the post if they choose to use it as an example of a good OR a poor question/answer. I think the label "favorite" is a rather poor term; in actual use, replacing "favorite" with "saved" would mirror how it is used.

Comment: in that question, the answerer has stated that "There are a few badges the OP will earn at 10, 25, and 100 favorites". What badges had he mentioned?

Comment: A second answer to the linked question explains:  "

As I see it, the favorite star implies "worth revisiting, for whatever reason".

There are a few badges the OP will earn at 10, 25, and 100 favorites -- if you can ask a question that a lot of people think is worth revisiting, I believe that is noteworthy."  Poor posts can be just as noteworthy as great posts.  Whether there should be a badge for those who post noteworthy terrible questions, is another debate.

Comment: Favorites are designed to help you get a list of questions which are interesting enough in some way and you want them to be easily found. And these can be one of your questions too. Unfortunately my favorite list has overgrown and searching is very difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users can *always* mark their own question as favourite questions.

It does make *some* sense, though, since it lets them follow through updates on the question *and* the answers from the relevant tab in their profile.

(I agree that it feels a bit redundantly frivolous, though.)

Comment: I don't understand your last phrase. Notice that each user can to have his/her own reasons to mark as favorite these questions. For example I do it if I need to study part of the reasoning in an answer, or well if I want to continue studying my thread of thought of one of myself questions.

Comment: @user759001: The point here is that you can find these questions, they are in your own profile.  So I've never seen the point of adding your *own* question to your favourite, with the exception of badge gaming (which I'll admit to have done before in this case, as it has exactly 0 influence, and the gaming extent is very limited).

Comment: @AsafKaragila Although I haven't done this with any of my questions (but as I only have $2$, that's not really too surprising), also note that in addition that if you ask many questions, marking your own questions as favorites (but soon to be renamed to, in my opinion a more appropriate name of bookmark) is a fairly easy way to have a separate list of a smaller number of your questions you can easily find & check on later. Of course, you can also do that in other ways, such as browser bookmarks, but this is method to do something similar within Math SE.

Comment: @John: Thanks, that does make sense. In my experience, people who do that, tend to automatically do it for all their questions. Hence my remark.

Comment: In my view, important concerns are for example (in my opinion) statistics about how many downvotes get a generic *New contibutor* in his/her first day, or his/her first few questions, asked in the main site, and the impact (that I evoke from my ignorance) that it can to have in their accounts in this site. I can to evoke more examples, I don't like some situations.

Comment: @JohnOmielan  I agree that "favorite" should be changed to "saved", or as you suggest, "bookmarked", because that's exactly how most users use the feature.  Better to more accurately describe how it is most commonly used, than to imply, using the word "favorites", that every vote to make a post a favorite, is by a user who very much likes the post.

Comment: @JohnOmielan  re-reading your comment in this thread, you say "...marking your own questions as favorites (but soon to be renamed to, in my opinion a more appropriate name of bookmark...", I hadn't earlier (in  my last comment to you) noticed the "soon to be renamed" portion.  Is SE about to implement this change?  That would be awesome if they do.

Comment: @amWhy Yes, Yaakov Ellis, of SE, has officially announced this. In the main Meta [The Follow Questions and Answers feature is now live across the Network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/562482) from $6$ days ago, the second point of "We are still planning on two more related releases:" says "We will be **renaming the Favorites feature to Bookmarks.**" Unfortunately, no timeline is given for this, but I assume it'll happen relatively soon.

Comment: Oh that's awesome to hear.  Thanks, @JohnOmielan, for the news!